# WARNING neutron_lbaas.services.loadbalancer.drivers.haproxy.namespace_driver [-] Stats socket not found for pool

Tags: namespaces, openstack, pool

I have the following problem with OpenStack Libery lbaas. When I create a new pool this error starts to appear:

WARNING neutron_lbaas.services.loadbalancer.drivers.haproxy.namespace_driver [-] Stats socket not found for pool

I have deployed controller and compute services on the same node and I use lbaas not lbaasv2. I use linuxBridgeDriver.

Can you help with that, cause I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me the messages stopped as soon as I assigned a VIP to the LBaaS.

The stats socket is in a directory with the ID as part of it:

```
/var/lib/neutron/lbaas/<lbaas-id>
```

But this directory is created the moment you assign a VIP.